# ошибка при работе toLocaleDateString

Tags: javascript, html

```
    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(-24);
    date.toLocaleDateString();
```

вывод :"28.08.2018"

```
date.setHours(-24).toLocaleDateString();
```

Выводит ошибку Uncaught TypeError: date.setHours(...).toLocaleDateString is not a function
не могу понять, как сделать это в одну строчку, и можно ли сделать? в две строки работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();

// в две строчки
date.setHours(-24);
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());

// в одну строчку
console.log( (date = new Date(date.setHours(-24))).toLocaleDateString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `setHours()` устанавливает указанное количество часов к указанной дате и возвращает количество миллисекунд с 1 января 1970 00:00:00 UTC до получившейся даты.

Ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: date.setHours(...).toLocaleDateString

появляется потому что вы пытаетесь это количество секунд перевести в дату в строковом формате, что невозможного для данного типа значения.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.setHours(-24));
console.log(typeof(date.setHours(-24)));
```